# Getting embedcode from youtube link through xml deserializer parsing

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can anybody pleae tell me how can I get the embedcode from youtubelink in Xml feed through xml deserializer parsing.In Xml Feed   [http://teluguone.com/movies/moviesXml.php]  I have links like

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLUbJtlBtHM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0HEZC-58Nw. So how can I get embedcode from the above links through xml Deserialize parsing.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just split the link by '=' and get the second part of the result

Comment: I have other links also in the feed such as  http://youtu.be/p9OBW4C_WSU,  http://youtu.be/m8jX2jbSyBo.How can I get code from these links.

Comment: the split it by '/' and get the second part

Comment: I had both in single feed.how I should apply.And using split raising an error no reference like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is in two different formats, just do a simple check. If the url contains

```
private string GetCode(string url)
{
    if (url.Contains("?v="))
    {
        var parts=url.Split('=');
        return parst[1];
    }

    return url.Split('/')[1];
}
```

maybe also adding some error checking.

Comment: I want to pass the videoId to var url=awaitYouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(videoId, YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);.I am getting link from movie.MovieWatchLink.From this I need to extract videoId.And this movie.MovieWatchLink contains different url formats as I mentioned above.please,Can you help me how can I check.

Comment: Movie movie;
     public VideoPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var app = App.Current as App;
            movie = app.selectedMovie;
            string video = movie.MovieWatchLink;  In this string video I get youtube Urls of different formats when I select an item in listbox.Now please tell me how colud I extract videoId from this youtube url and pass to player.      Many Thanks in advance